# Error when recovering snapshot Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I created a snapshot with curl from 1 cluster. When I try to recover a snapshot with curl on another cluster, 2nd Cluster cannot allocate all indices. Cluster 1 has 2 nodes, cluster 2 has 1 node. I have a file "snap-hb19TYAWQ1SFZvTzd-2AkA.dat" in snapshot folder. With cmd "_cluster/allocation/explain" I can see a problem. How to solve it?

```
nested: IndexShardRestoreFailedException[failed to restore snapshot [05_01_24/hb19TYAWQ1SFZvTzd-2AkA]]; 
nested: SnapshotMissingException[[my_repo:05_01_24/hb19TYAWQ1SFZvTzd-2AkA] is missing]; 
nested: NoSuchFileException[blob object [snap-hb19TYAWQ1SFZvTzd-2AkA.dat] not found]; 
- manually close or delete the index [tasklist-task-8.2.3_2023-11-30] in order to retry to restore the snapshot again or use the reroute API to force the allocation of an empty primary shard
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here are some steps to diagnose the issue:

1. Make sure you connected repository from 2nd cluster as `read-only`. The cluster that you want to restore a snapshot.
2. [Verify](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/verify-snapshot-repo-api.html) the repository.
3. For testing, create an index with one doc, get snapshot from 1st cluster and restore it into 2nd cluster.
4. Enable debug mode for snapshot and check the elasticsearch logs.

---

# example for s3

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "transient": {
    "logger.org.elasticsearch.snapshots" : "DEBUG",
    "logger.org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3": "DEBUG",
    "logger.com.amazonaws" : "DEBUG"
  }
}
```

5. let me know :)

Comment: 1) Repository is URL type, it is readonly 2) I verified repo, everything is ok. 3) I recovered a snapshot with about 300 indices. Half of them is assigned to shards. Half of them is not. I have 294 shards. 4) I enabled debug, but i have the same logs.

Comment: "Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: blob object [snap-hb19TYAWQ1SFZvTzd-2AkA.dat] not found",
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.snapshots.SnapshotMissingException: [my_repo:05_01_24/hb19TYAWQ1SFZvTzd-2AkA] is missing",
"Caused by: org.elasticsearch.action.NoShardAvailableActionException",
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: all shards failed",

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That specific snapshot can be corrupted. Try to create a new snapshot and restore again.

Comment: I created snapshots 3 times, I couldn't recover snapshots all 3 times.

Comment: It's weird. Can you please check if there is enough space in the 2nd cluster to recover all inidces

Comment: yes, there is enough space, 2 GB is free